# How to get attributes from through table in query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm making a simple shopping cart. I have a Cart model, a Product model and a through table CartItems. These are the associations:

```
models.Cart.belongsToMany(models.Product, { through: 'CartItems', as: 'items' })
models.Product.belongsToMany(models.Cart, { through: "CartItems" });
```

These are the definitions of the models:

**Cart Model**

```
var Cart = sequelize.define('Cart', {
    userId: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'User',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    totalPrice: DataTypes.FLOAT
});
```

**Product Model**

```
var Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    code: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    price: DataTypes.FLOAT
});
```

**CartItems Model**
In this model I added a quantity and price attribute because I read somewhere that it's good to have a history of what the price was when they made the order. And the quantity attribute because I just want to change the quantity if another product is added instead of adding another row.

```
var CartItem = sequelize.define('CartItem', {
    CartId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ProductId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    price: DataTypes.FLOAT
});
```

I know this might not be the best way to do things but even if I change the implementation I would like to know: how do I access an attribute that's in the *through* table?

Specifically I'm trying to do the following for the checkout function:

```
Cart.prototype.checkout = async function () {
    let cartItemArray = await this.getItems({
      include: [{
        model: Product,
        through: {
          attributes: ['quantity'],
        }
      }]
    });
    cartItemArray = cartItemArray.map((item) => {
      return {
        code: item.code,
        price: item.price,
        quantity: item.quantity
      };
    });
    let total = getTotalPrice(cartItemArray);
    return total;
};
```

Comment: it is good to have price history but you not need to update the price on the base of the quantity. you should multiply it with quantity to get it. if there any discount put that also in that table. so you can show it for later.

Answer (score 3):

## First, a few warnings

**Warning 1.** You have a `price` field both in your `Product` model and in your `CartItem` model. Are you sure you want this? In your attempt to write that `checkout()` method, when you do `item.price`, which of those prices did you want to get? My intuition tells me you didn't really want to have two fields, but if you really do, consider renaming one of them to avoid ambiguity.

**Warning 2.** You have a `totalPrice` in your `Cart` model... Is this field supposed to keep track of the sum of the prices of the associated products? If yes, that is a bad idea, remove that field altogether and whenever you need the sum, compute it at that very moment, because keeping duplicate data like this is very error prone (you must ensure they are in sync).

---

## Mistake 1

You explicitly defined the junction table model, i.e. `CartItem`, with the following code:

```
var CartItem = sequelize.define('CartItem', { /* ... */ });
```

So far so good. But when you define the many-to-many relationship, you made  a mistake. You used `through: "CartItems"` but you should have used `through: "CartItem"`. Actually, the best practice in this case is to refer directly to the model, since you have it: `through: CartItem`. Because of this Sequelize ended up ignoring your model and creating a junction table automatically without your extra fields `price` and `quantity`.

---

## Mistake 2

In your attempt to write the `checkout()` method you did:

```
this.getItems({
    include: [{
        model: Product,
        through: {
            attributes: ['quantity'],
        }
    }]
});
```

This does not make sense. Recall that `Item` is just an alias you set up for `Product`. Running this code yields `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Product is not associated to Product!`.

Instead, you can simply perform a `this.getItems()` without any parameters at all.

---

## Mistake 3

Next, you wrote the code:

```
return {
    code: item.code,
    price: item.price,
    quantity: item.quantity
};
```

which suggests that you were expecting that `quantity` came as another field alongside `code`. This is incorrect. `code` is a field from the `Product` model while `quantity` is a field from the `CartItem` model. Sequelize will not retrieve them "flattened" like this. Instead, the fields from the association itself come nested in the query result, like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "code": null,
    "name": "test",
    "price": null,
    "createdAt": "2018-03-11T19:11:12.862Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-11T19:11:12.862Z",
    "CartItem": {
        "CartId": 1,
        "ProductId": 1,
        "quantity": 2,
        "price": 1.5,
        "createdAt": "2018-03-11T19:11:13.047Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-03-11T19:11:13.047Z"
    }
}
```

Therefore, instead of `item.quantity` there, you should use `item.CartItem.quantity`.

---

## Summarizing

The answer to the question in title, "*How to get attributes from through table in query?*" is simply "just do the query, i.e., `this.getItems()` in your case, since the attributes from through table come in the result by default".

It's just that you made a few other mistakes and of course, it didn't work.